# How do you compare two or more image files of the same size?

Tags: c++, image, comparison

Basically I want to write a program that compares two different image files that are the exact same size and can tell if they are exactly the same (visually). Example:

```
                if( img1.jpg == img2.jpg)
                {
                       x = 1;
                }

                if( x == 1)
                {
                       do stuff;
                }

                else
                {
                       do other stuff;
                }
```

Comment: I tried using memcmp but it didn't really work

Comment: To convert it to text and than compare it.

Comment: If they should be exactly equal, why not check a md5 of the content?

Comment: @Babblo Unless the hash is saved for later, it's more efficient - and easier - to read until a difference is found (hashing would require a full read). On the other hand, calling the `md5sum` program ..

Answer (score 1):

Compare byte by byte using fopen, fgetc or use [opencv for more](http://sublimated.wordpress.com/2011/01/25/image-difference-with-opencv/) sensible comparison.